# Is there a Gift Aid (UK) extension compatible with 4.6+?

Tags: contributions, gift-aid-extension

There are several GiftAid extensions (ones I've found linked to below) for CiviCRM but I am having difficulty finding any that claim support for version 4.6+ and posts on many of them seem to be a few years out of date.

Is anybody using a Gift Aid extension they can recommend?

The two I've found are:
http://www.compucorp.co.uk/blog/civicrm-gift-aid-instructions-v43
https://civicrm.org/blogs/rajesh/civigiftaid-extension

Thanks in advance for any suggestions anyone can provide!

Answer (score 7):

Big thanks for supporting GiftAid extension!

The Civi4.6 branch has been actively worked on in the past few months. A few improvements and new features have been added into the extension. Although the new version is still under testings, we decide to establish an alpha3 release from the latest changes so we can share the results with the community and we can help to push the progress further forward.

Latest changes:

- CiviCRM 4.6.x compatibility has been implemented
- Added line item support for contributions include more than one item
- GiftAid Report improvement

The new pre-release can be downloaded here:
https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.giftaid/releases/tag/v3.0beta

You can also follow our Github repository for the latest update.

Moreover, we have recently implemented GiftAid Webform Integration module for Drupal as well. We will open a Drupal project page for this soon. It can be found here:
https://github.com/compucorp/giftaid_webform_integration

Look forward to hearing feedback from you.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to contact both Veda (NFP) and CompuCorp on this, but no answer yet.

However, today I found the Compucorp Git repository, where there is a 4.6 branch for the Gift Aid module, which they seem to have been working on for the last few months. There is a commit from Jun 24 2015 labelled "pre release", so it may be close to release. Yay!

https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.giftaid/commits/civi4.6

Answer (score 3):

Its being developed now......
https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.giftaid/tree/civi4.6

Answer (score 1):

I think you should Contact the developer directly. you can find contact details from github. They should have some news.

Comment: Sam, did you get an answer on this?  It would be useful for others with the same question (like me!)  Andy

Comment: Hi Andy, apologies only just logged in and seen this, think I need to check my notification settings. No I'm afraid I haven't got an answer yet, I decided to simply add a custom field for it and collect the address details as part of the donation profile ourselves, inefficient but I felt more reliable vs unsupported extensions.

Comment: please check Jonathan's answer. Recently I was contacted by compucorp  rep, asking to test the alpha release of 4.6 branch. Which is still buggy. Things like the financial type are not to be included is still including. For those donations are not eligible for giftaid are also included, unless you chose "YES" when creating a batch, which was not the case in previous release. I guess they need some funding perhaps to make it faster

Comment: Looks like this extension being worked on here very recently https://github.com/robinmitra?tab=activity

Answer (score 1):

I asked the same question a couple of weeks ago (June 2016) to Compucorp, the company which has developed the Gift Aid extension for CiviCRM. They directed me to this link:

https://github.com/compucorp/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.giftaid/releases/tag/v3.0beta

This release worked very well for us on 4.6.12.